# adding a line break using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment for school. I have everything working the way it should be. The only thing that is wrong is how the output is formatted. I am not understanding why I am receiving the output formatted the way it is. I am using javascript, and I am creating nodes and appending them as a child element. My main goal is for each piece of information to be formatted and placed on its own line. this is my javascript function.

```
function createUserid()

     {
     var firstString = window.prompt ( "Enter first name", "" ); 
             //documentwrite
              var lower = firstString.toLowerCase();
             // firstString.substring(0,4)
             // firstString.concat
     var lastString = window.prompt ( "Enter last name", "" );
     var lowlast = lastString.toLowerCase();
     var socialString = window.prompt ( "Enter social security number without dashes", "" );

     var ln = lowlast.substring(0,4);       //first 4 of last name
     var ls = socialString.substring(5,9);  //last 4 of social
     var fs = socialString.substring(0,5);  //first 5 of social
     var fn = lower.substring(0,4);         //first 4 of first name


             //var user = docoument.write("<p>" + "Username: " + lastString +
             //var pass = <p>"Password: " +

             //var myDiv = document.getElementById('here');
             //myDiv.innerHTML = ____ ;


        var e = document.getElementById('info');
        var o = document.getElementById('here');

        //creating 2 elements: p, br
        var newPara = document.createElement('p');
        var tBR = document.createElement('br');

        //prepare text nodes
        var first = document.createTextNode('First name: ' + firstString);
        var last = document.createTextNode('Last name: ' + lastString);
        var social = document.createTextNode('Social Security #: ' + socialString);
        var userN = document.createTextNode('Username: ' + ln + ls);
        var passW = document.createTextNode('Password: ' + fs + fn);

        //put together paragraph            
        newPara.appendChild(first);
        newPara.appendChild(tBR);
        newPara.appendChild(last);
        newPara.appendChild(tBR);
        newPara.appendChild(social);
        newPara.appendChild(tBR);
        newPara.appendChild(userN);
        newPara.appendChild(tBR);
        newPara.appendChild(passW); 

        //insert into div id of info
        document.getElementById('info').appendChild(newPara);





        o.style.display = 'none';
        e.style.display = 'block';      

    }
```

this is the output I am receiving[image]

this is how the output is supposed to look.[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are appending same node again and again.

```
newPara.appendChild(first);
    newPara.appendChild(tBR);
    newPara.appendChild(last);
    newPara.appendChild(tBR);  <--- this node gets moved, since you append it again.
    newPara.appendChild(social);
    newPara.appendChild(tBR);
    newPara.appendChild(userN);
    newPara.appendChild(tBR);  <--- this is where tBR will be at last.
    newPara.appendChild(passW);
```

Instead do this :

```
 var first = document.createTextNode('First name: ' + firstString + '<br/>');
```

Or this :

```
        newPara.appendChild(first);
        newPara.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        newPara.appendChild(last);
        newPara.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));  
 .................................
```

Documentation here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild

> Adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent
>   node. If the node already exists it is removed from current parent
>   node, then added to new parent node.

Comment: Oh ok. I understand now about the nodes now. I have already tried what you had suggest, but that does not work. It outputs the actual text <br/> in the line as well

Comment: Your second suggestion works out perfectly. I did not think you could do that for some reason. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That might be because you were creating text node which will take '<br/>' as a string.

Answer (score 1):

If `child` has already been inserted, [`element.appendChild(child)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) removes it from where it was before inserting it at its new location.

Use [`node.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode) to make copies of the child, or just use [`document.createElement('br')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) again and again (possibly in a loop to avoid repeating yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var first = document.createTextNode('First name: ' + firstString + '<br>');
var last = document.createTextNode('Last name: ' + lastString + '<br>');
var social = document.createTextNode('Social Security #: ' + socialString + '<br>');
var userN = document.createTextNode('Username: ' + ln + ls + '<br>');
var passW = document.createTextNode('Password: ' + fs + fn + '<br>');
```

Comment: The asker will end up with a literal `<br>` in the rendered output.